Is there another way to calculate receptive field size for temporal convolutional networks?
In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.12853 on page 4 a TCN-model is used where the receptive field is 253 frames, kernel size is 3 and 6 residual blocks are used. As far as I know the formula for the receptive field size would be: $$ (kernel size)* 2^{layer depth-1} *\#blocks $$ Since the answer should necessarily be even, how can this be?
